# Fetching a single record with Ember data - non-conventional URL format

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My server API has a route, *'/user'*, which fetches a SINGLE user record based on the client's authentication cookie, and no ID.

How do I make this call in Ember Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `pathForType` and `buildUrl` on your user adapter:

```
App.UserAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var decamelized = Ember.String.decamelize(type); 
    //return Ember.String.pluralize(decamelized);
    return decamelized;
  },
  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    var url = [],
        host = get(this, 'host'),
        prefix = this.urlPrefix();

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }
    if (id!==-1) { url.push(id); }  // This will exclude the id for this request

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    return url;
  },
});
```

then use

```
this.store.find('user', -1);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/147/edit

Comment: But I only want to fetch a single record.

Comment: There ya go, this above will handle it just for the user model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you want to fetch the user, but either way, you'll want to create your own adapter. You'll likely want to override one or more of the find methods (`find`, `findAll`, `findMany`, `findQuery`), depending on your situation. Check to see if the type is `user` first. If it is, implement your custom logic. If not, just call the super method on whichever adapter you extend.

If you give me a little more information on how you want to access user models, I could probably help more.

EDIT: It seems like you might only need to override the `buildURL` function. You might have to return more than just `/user`, such as the host and prefix, but this should give you the gist. Check [the source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.5/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L409) of the REST adapter to see how they do it by default.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    buildUrl: function(type, id) {
        if (type.typeKey === 'user' && id === 1) {
            return '/user';
        } else {
            return this._super.buildUrl.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, say that the currently logged-in user has an ID of '1'.

I want to be able to do this:

`App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('user', this.store.find('user', 1));
 }
});`

without having to specify the '1' parameter (since like I said, the server will find that ID by reading the cookie)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. However I don't want to use an ID parameter at all. The server determines which record to retrieve using the authentication cookie; no ID ever needs to be passed.

Comment: Then what you'll likely want to do is just pass `null` or a global constant like `USER_ID`. That way you can still use the `find` function which expects a single record returned.